# R create a vector from conditional operation on matrix

Tags: r

I would like to create a vector from a matrix by applying a conditional statement to each column.  The conditional statement being, if any value in the column exceeds a fixed threshold, then the value in the vector should be the last row of that column, if it does not then the value in the vector should be 0.  In the end, I should end up with a vector that is the same number of columns as my matrix.  Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: `apply` by column, there is a function called `any`......

Comment: ah, duh. let me take a crack at that and post my code for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100),nrow=10,ncol=10)
apply(mat, 2, function(v) {
  ifelse (any(v > 0.7), v[length(v)],0)
})
```

Comment: beat me to it. but yeah that's the gist.

Comment: @user1790121 Ah, sorry, didn't see the comments before posting.

Comment: sorry for the delay in accepting answer.  Thanks for the help!