# Conditions & Subtraction from Matrix in R

Tags: r

I've looked at [R create a vector from conditional operation on matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865023/r-create-a-vector-from-conditional-operation-on-matrix), and using a similar solution does not yield what I want (and I'm not sure why).

My goal is to evaluate `df` with the following condition: `if df > 2, df -2, else 0`

Take `df`:

```
a <- seq(1,5)
b <- seq(0,4)
df <- cbind(a,b) %>% as.data.frame()
```

`df` is simply:

```
a b
1 0
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 4
```

`df_final` should look like this after a suitable function:

```
a b
0 0
0 0
1 0
2 1
3 2
```

I applied the following function with the result, and I'm not sure why it doesn't work (further explanation of a solution would be appreciated)

```
apply(df,2,function(df){
     ifelse(any(df>2),df-2,0)
 })
```

Yielding the following:

```
 a  b 
-1 -2
```

Thank you SO community!

Comment: Get rid of your `any()`. `ifelse(df > 2, df - 2, 0)` should work fine.

Comment: Yes! I had to convert back to a data.frame but this is perfect - thank you! I appreciate fixes to my own functions (as simple as they are :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's fix your function and understand why it didn't work:

```
apply(df,  # apply to df
       2,  # to each *column* of df 
       function(df){  # this function. Call the function argument (each column) df 
                      #  (confusing because this is the same name as the data frame...)
         ifelse(  # Looking at each column...
              any(df > 2),  # if there are any values > 2
              df - 2,       # then df - 2
              0             # otherwise 0
          )
 })
```

`any()` returns a single value. `ifelse()` returns something the same shape as the test, so by making your test `any(df > 2)` (a single value), `ifelse()` will also return a single value.

Let's fix this by (a) changing the function to be of a different name than the input (for readability) and (b) getting rid of the `any`:

```
apply(df,  # apply to df
       2,  # to each *column* of df 
       function(x){   # this function. Call the function argument (each column) x
         ifelse(  # Looking at each column...
              x > 2,  # when x is > 2
              df - 2, # make it x - 2
              0       # otherwise 0
          )
 })
```

`apply` is made for working on matrices. When you give it a data frame, the first thing it does is convert it to a matrix. If you want the result to be a data frame, you need to convert it back to a data frame.

Or we can use `lapply` instead. `lapply` returns a `list`, and by assigning it to the columns of `df` with `df[] <- lapply()`, we won't need to convert. (And since `lapply` doesn't do the matrix conversion, it knows by default to apply the function to each column.)

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x > 2, x - 2, 0))
```

---

As a side note, `df <- cbind(a,b) %>% as.data.frame()` is a more complicated way of writing `df <- data.frame(a, b)`

Answer (score 2):

Create the 'out' dataset by subtracting 2, then replace the values that are based on a logical condition to 0

```
out <- df - 2
out[out < 0] <- 0
```

---

Or in a single step

```
(df-2) * ((df - 2) > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using apply

```
a <- seq(1,5)
b <- seq(0,4)
df <- cbind(a,b) %>% as.data.frame()

new_matrix <- apply(df, MARGIN=2,function(i)ifelse(i >2, i-2,0)) 
new_matrix
###if you want it to return a tibble/df
new_tibble <- apply(df, MARGIN=2,function(i)ifelse(i >2, i-2,0)) %>% as_tibble()
```